# Balance a Scale with an Array of Weights

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, combinations

I have been given the following prompt:
Suppose you have a weight on one side of a scale. Given an array of other weights, see if the scale will balance. You can use weights on either side, and you don't have to use all the weights.

I am trying to implement the solution using javascript and have been able to solve the problem for one of the conditions by accumulating the weights until there is match. Ultimately this will only work for the case of adding to the left side of the scale but this is not optimal considering that the weights can be added to the right side as well. Below is my implementation so far.

```js
const balance = (arrayOfWeights) => {
  //Sort the array and pop off the max number to be stored on the right side of the scale 
  let right = arrayOfWeights.sort().pop();
  let balanced;
  let weight;

  const subroutine = (lSide, rSide, weightList) => {
    //Determine if there is a direct match
    if(lSide === rSide) {
      balanced = true;
      return balanced;
    }
    //Return false if a match hasn't been found
    if(weightList.length === 0) {
      balanced = false;
      return balanced
    }
    //Shift the first element of the array to be added to left side
    weight = weightList.shift();
    subroutine(lSide + weight , rSide, weightList);
  }
  subroutine(0, right, arrayOfWeights);
  return balanced;
};

//Array of weights to be passed to balance function
let weights = [3,6,2,5,1];
```

Comment: You first need to write down all the steps you need to check all the combinations, then you start writing code.

Comment: Sounds like this is similar to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem. Also asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55149/split-a-set-of-numbers-into-2-sets-where-the-sum-of-each-set-is-as-close-to-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, could use some basic recursion to just go through all combos. Suppose you have the situation where you have 3 options:

```
1. include the weight on the left
2. include the weight on the right
3. dont include the weight
```

The general idea would look like:

```java
f(A[],k,n){
  if(weights on both sides are euqal) return 
  if(k==n) return
  A[k]=0 //not included 
  f(A,k+1,n)
  A[k]=1 // included on the left
  f(A,k+1,n)
  A[k]=2 // included on the right
  f(A,k+1,n)
}
```

where `0` represents the weight at `k` not being included, `1` represents the weight at `k` included on the left, and `2` represents the weight at `k` included on the right. This is what i did in java (don't know much javascript):

```java
static void print(int A[],int B[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if(A[i]==1) System.out.println(B[i]+" is on the left");
            else if(A[i]==2) System.out.println(B[i]+" is on the right");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    static boolean sum(int A[],int B[],int[] w){
        int left=0;
        int right=0;
        if(w[1]==1) left+= w[0];
        else if (w[1]==2) right+= w[0];

        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            if(A[i]==1) left+= B[i];
            if(A[i]==2) right+= B[i];
        }
        if(right==left) return true;

        return false;
    }


    static void g(int A[],int B[],int k,int n,int[] w){

        if(sum(B,A,w)){//works
            print(B,A);
            return;
        }
        if(k==n) return;//doesnt work

        B[k]=0;//not included
        g(A,B,k+1,n,w);
        B[k]=1;//included on the left
        g(A,B,k+1,n,w);
        B[k]=2;//included on the right
        g(A,B,k+1,n,w);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int A[] = {4,5,6,7};//array of weights

        // put 0 if ith element not included 
        // put 1 if ith element is on the left  
        // put 2 if ith element is on the right
        int B[] = new int[A.length];

        // weight you start with: 
        // w[0] is weight amount w[1]
        // is whether its on the left right or neither (1,2,0)
        int[] w = {6,1};
        g(A,B,0,A.length,w);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question that was resurrected recently.  Neither answer given so far tries to do this with Javascript as requested.  Here is one that should work, but won't win any awards for efficiency.  Almost certainly there is some well-known algorithm that would do better than this (which is `O (n ^ 2)` in the worst case.)  But this is at least fairly elegant.

```js
const canBalance = ([w, ...ws], left = 0, right = 0) => 
  left == right && left + right > 0
    ? true
  : w == undefined
    ? false
  : canBalance (ws, left, right) ||
    canBalance (ws, left + w, right) ||
    canBalance (ws, left, right + w)


console .log (canBalance ([3, 6, 2, 5, 1]))  //=> true
console .log (canBalance ([1, 2, 4, 8, 16])) //=> false
console .log (canBalance ([5, 5]))           //=> true
```

We have two simple cases. If the scales are already balanced (and not empty) we return `true`. If there are no weights left, we return `false`.  (Note that these checks have to come in this order, or we will miss the case when the last weight makes the balance.)

In the main case, we test three possibilities, short-circuiting if one of them is true.  The cases are if we exclude the first weight, put it on the left side, or put it on the right side, recurring then with a shorter set of weights.

Because this is already likely far from optimal, I didn't bother with one obvious optimization.  We could check that if all the remaining weights combine to less than the difference between the sides, and if so return `false. That would involve adding this before the final case:

```js
  : w + sum (ws) < Math .abs (left - right)
    ? false
```

using an obvious `sum` function.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution a wrote in java, it will balance the scale using one or two stones if required from the available weights.

```
public class scaleBalancing {
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int weights[] = {1,6,4,9};
        int balance[] = {6,4};
        ArrayList stoneA = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList stoneB = new ArrayList();
        boolean stone1 = false;
        boolean stone2 = false;
        for(int j=0;j<weights.length;j++){
            if(j==weights.length&&(weights[j]+balance[0]==weights[j-1]+balance[1]||weights[j]+balance[1]==weights[j-1]+balance[0])){
                stone1=true;
                stone2=true;
                stoneA.add(weights[j]);
                stoneB.add(weights[j-1]);
            }  
            else if(j<weights.length-1&&(weights[j]+balance[0]==weights[j+1]+balance[1]||weights[j]+balance[1]==weights[j+1]+balance[0])){
                stone1=true;
                stone2=true;
                stoneA.add(weights[j]);
                stoneB.add(weights[j+1]);
            }
            else if(weights[j]+balance[0]==balance[1]){
                stone1 =true;
                stoneA.add(weights[j]);
            }
            else if(weights[j]+balance[1]==balance[0]){
                stone2 = true;
                stoneB.add(weights[j]);
            }
        }
        if(stone1&&stone2){
            for(int i=0;i<stoneA.size();i++){
                System.out.println("{"+stoneA.get(i)+","+stoneB.get(i)+"}");
            }
        }
        else if(stone1){
            for(int i=0;i<stoneA.size();i++){
                System.out.println("{"+stoneA.get(i)+"}");
            }
        }
        else if(stone2){
            for(int i=0;i<stoneB.size();i++){
                System.out.println("{"+stoneB.get(i)+"}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the request was "to implement the solution using javascript".  Do you write JS?  If so, could you convert your code to it?

Comment: It is easy to translate the code to JS if you get the logic behind the code.

Comment: Of course it is, if you know both.  I was asking if you did, because the question did ask for JS.  Instead of trying to convert yours, I wrote my own answer, which turns out fairly elegant.

Comment: I am still college student and hobbyist programmer, I did js like before I started my bachelors program, now I am in third semester my solution in java is nowhere near efficient but yet it is working